# Unable to add variable "Max_Input_Vars = 10000" to Additional Directives field in Nginx Settings in Plesk Obsidian

Tags: php, linux, nginx, plesk, nginx-config

I have set up a domain (beinternet.co.uk) on Plesk and the WordPress theme I am wanting to use for a client requires upwards of 5000 Max Input Vars.
I have tried changing the value in php.ini file but this just defaults to the standard 1000 value.
I have tried adding the values to .htaccess file and that crashes the site with a 500 Server Error.

So now I have tried adding the line "Max_Input_Vars = 10000" to Additional Directives field in Nginx Settings and I get the error as below;

**Invalid nginx configuration: nginx: [emerg] unexpected end of file, expecting ";" or "}" in
/var/www/vhosts/system/beinternet.co.uk/conf/vhost_nginx.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed.**

Can anyone please offer some guidance or help with this? It's the first time I have ever had this issue. Many thanks in advance. :)

I have tried all the different options as explained in the main description but with no success.
I was expecting the values to be accepted by the server as I have never had a problem with this before.

Answer (score 0):

This must not go into the "Additional Nginx directives" field, but it is a PHP setting and needs to go into the "Additional PHP directives" field at the bottom of your PHP settings page.